# flask_mysqldb Delete FROM variable table

Tags: python, mysql, variables, flask, mysql-python

So i use flask_mysqldb in a Flask(Python website)

I'm trying to write a function to delete a row in any table.
It works perfectly when I hardcode the tablename, but what do I need to do to be able to use a variable instead?

```
@app.route('/delete/<string:table>/<string:id>', methods=['POST'])
@is_logged_in
def delete(table, id):
  # Create Cursor
  cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

  # Execute
  cur.execute("DELETE FROM %s WHERE id = %s", (table, id))

  mysql.connection.commit()

  cur.close()

  flash('%s deleted'(table), 'success')

  return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
```

Comment: Your code snippet seems to use a variable for the table name.  Are you getting an error when executing the delete function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cur.execute("DELETE FROM %s WHERE id = %s", (table, id))
```

should be

```
cur.execute("DELETE FROM %s WHERE id = %s" % (table, id))
```