# Python DELETE mysql/mariadb with a python variable not working

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I am trying to do something as described in the post below, I have simplified this with a basic python program, not using flask, just to prove my concept, but I'm having some issues.

[flask_mysqldb Delete FROM variable table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024806/flask-mysqldb-delete-from-variable-table)

My code is as follows;

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb

new = 'ksk'
mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='root', password='mypwd', 
database='customers')
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("DELETE FROM customer_info WHERE name = %s" % (new))

mariadb_connection.commit()
print('its gone')
```

this throws up an error saying in my table,

```
"unknown column 'ksk' in where clause"
```

this isn't true I can see a row where the name is ksk.

Furthermore to prove this, if I change my delete statement to:

```
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM customer_info WHERE name = 'ksk'
```

the row ksk gets successfully deleted. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Short answer:  Use comma instead of percent.

Comment: Tried this, it throws up an error that a string is not callable. The comma method works when using the SELECT feature not in the DELETE feature for some reason?

Comment: Your string is not being escaped/quoted. It's treated like a column name.

Comment: Please could you show me how to rectify that? Is putting the new = 'ksk' not suitable? Or do I need to quote as 'new' in my DELETE statement?

Comment: @PrimitiveSource - Since you have only one item, you need an extra comma:  `(new,)` to make it a "tuple".

Comment: Thank you for your help Rick, this has worked perfectly :-)

Answer (score 0):

https://pynative.com/python-mysql-execute-parameterized-query-using-prepared-statement/ --

> We then added those two columns value in the input **tuple** in sequential order and passed SQL update query and input tuple t0 cursor.execute() function,  remember tuple contain user data in sequential order of placeholders.
>
> The CURSOR’s execute() method takes an optional **second argument** containing a list of data values. each entry in the list must be in tuple format to associate with parameter markers in the statement.